# Hook home button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia-substrate

What method should I hook to register a home button press? SpringBoard's `menuButtonUp` isn't working for me. All of the answers I have seen on this site so far are not helpful since this would be using the private API.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this without using a private API.

Comment: You have no direct way of detecting it. However, you can track it by  the state change in the appDelegate..

Comment: Using the private APIs is fine. Please read the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Springboard's `_menuButtonUp` for iOS7 and `menuButtonUp` for iOS6

Comment: can you put more in detal? how to call this function.

Comment: It is a Springboard method. `[%c(SpringBoard) menuButtonUp];` might work.

Comment: This way need to jailbreak, any private API to do that?

Comment: Yes, you will need to jailbreak

Comment: It's _menuButtonUp: and menuButtonUp: Note the last colons :)